# What does the * do in CSS?

Tags: css

What does the star do? What is it called? For me it is some kind of wild card. What is it called so I can read about it?

```
#div {
  *zoom: 1; /*this ... *
   zoom : 1;
   display: inline;
   *display: inline; /*... and this, whats the difference? *
}
```

I know what this means (all elements):

```
* {
..css code
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In simple words, its the key to target css on different IE browser versions. It can also be called as an CSS Hack.

```
#div {
  *zoom: 1; /*Only works on IE7 and below*/
  zoom : 1;
  display: inline;
  *display: inline; /*Only works on IE7 and below*/
}
```

Means this CSS works only on IE7 and below. It's kind of a hack we can use to apply CSS on IE7 and below.

Here is how to target IE6, IE7, and IE8 Uniquely

```
#div{  
 color: red; /* all browsers, of course */  
 color : green\9; /* IE8 and below */  
 *color : yellow; /* IE7 and below */  
 _color : orange; /* IE6 */  
}
```

[CLICK HERE](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer) if you want learn more about browser specific CSS.

Answer (score 5):

`star-property hack` The IE family ignore the *, however, and apply the property without it.This hack is used in order to deliver style rules only to Internet Explorer 7 (and lower). It relies on a wrong DOM implementation that affects Explorer since 1997. According to the specifications, the actual root element of any well-formed (X)HTML document is the html element. Instead, Explorer 7 (and lower) considers the html element as wrapped in another unknown element.

Answer (score 3):

***property: value**

> Although Internet Explorer 7 corrected its behavior when a property
>   name is prefixed with an underscore or a hyphen, other
>   non-alphanumeric character prefixes are treated as they were in IE6.
>   Therefore, if you add a non-alphanumeric character such as an asterisk
>   (*) immediately before a property name, the property will be applied
>   in IE and not in other browsers. Unlike with the hyphen and underscore
>   method, the CSS specification makes no reservations for the asterisk
>   as a prefix, so use of this hack could result in unexpected behavior
>   as the CSS specifications evolve.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml

Answer (score 2):

In your context it seems to be the **star hack**. It does that property only applies in some versions of IE, depends of its use.

You could retrieve more info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_hack).

Answer (score 0):

`What does the * in css?` -> Selects all the elements after specified elements for eg. `div.red *{color: red;}` will result all color red after its class red even if you define the other color inside `div.red` hence you know `*` means `ALL` 
See **[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynHUL/)**

`* zoom: 1;` -> here you have placed `*` at first, so this would hack IE only that is this type of style works only in IE and other browsers neglect this.

`*` it is called asterisk in simple language and in coding language this is called **[Universal Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#universal-selector)**