# usage of * symbol in css

Tags: css, stylesheet

I found some stylesheets using `*` symbol on it. for example `*zoom: 1;` what does the `*` symbol stands. sometimes which appears like `[class*="span"]` this. can anybody clear me the usage of the symbol `*` in css

Comment: In a selector or a field name? The first example looks like a field name, but the second looks like a selector.

Comment: most commonly i see this in stylesheets `.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}` and sometimes ` margin-left: 2.564102564102564%;
    *margin-left: 2.5109110747408616%;` `[class*="span"]`

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [#1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563651/what-does-an-asterisk-do-in-a-css-property-name), [#2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204275/what-does-an-asterisk-do-in-a-css-selector), [#3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286427/what-does-an-asterisk-mean-next-to-a-css-property)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS reset - purpose of asterik within a style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690642/css-reset-purpose-of-asterik-within-a-style)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965548/what-does-the-do-in-css/15965913#15965913

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`*zoom` is a hack that applies it ie6 and ie7. `* { }` is a wildcard (matches all elements or subset; if used like `#header *` it would apply to all descendants of `#header`). `[class*="span"]` matches elements that have a `class` with the word "span" anywhere.

Comment: Also to be noted, some developers(even me) uses `* {margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: 0;}` to reset defaults, but for performance conscious developers, this selector is a big performance hit..

Comment: Actually, Mr. Alien, the * { } selector when used on it's own isn't heavier on performance than what a single h1 { } would be. However combining it with something else such as #header * { } is heavy and is generally adviced against.

Answer (score 2):

If * is used an independent selector, it means all.
But if used inside the attribute selector [ ], it means "contains". For example, you have

> [class*="span"]

. It means, it will select all elements that has a class which has a "span" somewhere in the class name.

It also used as CSS hack if it's inside the style value.

Comment: why down vote? it was in his question! I was just explaining the different usage of asterisk.

Answer (score -1):

It is a wildcard which select all elements.

For example, if you apply margin to every element on entire page you can use:

```
* {
    margin: 50px;
}
```

You can also use this within sub-selections, for example the following would add a margin to all elements within a paragraph tag:

```
p * {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

See this:- http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/1204290/2256325

Regarding you example, let me tell you that  if you add asterisk (*) immediately before a property name, the property will be applied in IE and not in other browsers. Its only applicable to version 7 or below .

Source :-http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml

Comment: Because this answer only partially answers the question. It does not address the specific queries within the question. See @kalley's answer for a thorough and sufficient answer.

Comment: @BenM oh...sorry i didn't read the question properly. Let me correct it.

Comment: @BenM Btw, what do you mean by copy-paste. I have provided the link to the question. Everyone learns from somewhere i.e official documentation, SO  etc. Would you call that copy-paste ?

Answer (score -1):

In addition to using the asterisk (at the start of a property name) to select only for older IE browsers, for CSS the many varied details are at w3.org:

CSS2.1 -- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html

CSS3 -- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/